# composer error /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, laravel, composer-php

I have problem when I write any commando with composer

bash: /c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

I no have Idea about that

Comment: Please write a detailed information about your system. And the error result which will help you to get your answer.

Comment: my system is Windows 7. I am running  XAMPP, PHP 7.2. the error is when I write any command in console about composer, composer update, composer install, composer -v not work. my PC work fine the last week but I start the week with this error,

Comment: Did you put your php/compser path into temporary variable??

Comment: NO. How I do that? I put  in control panel-> advanced option -> entornal variable.. C;\composer . But did not work

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing external variable thats required for you to run composer.

First off install composer. 
And then add 
`C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin` into your external variables which should work fine.

*Replace `your_username` with your username

Comment: i go to
C:\Users\omar\AppData\Roaming\Composer but vendor  no exist (Select hidden folder in option) I only see 2 files
"keys.tags.pub",
"keys.dev.pub"

Comment: install composer then you'll be able to see

Comment: And also check if php exists in your external variables

Comment: nop. i unistall and reinstall composer two time and nothing :(

Comment: is php included in your external variable?

Comment: in windows 7 Check if the composer is in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin if its availabe add this instead

Comment: I dont know. First time I have this problem. in www.composer only explain the installation about composer.exe. I alwasy run this .exe and this ok. previous I installed xammp.

Comment: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin no exist! previous unistall exist but I install composer.exe 2 times and nothing

Comment: search for Composer folder in your filesystem and maybe find vendor bin folder from there and place in in your path